# CSS rotation behaves different than PHP

Tags: php, css, rotation

I'm trying to fix the image rotation on preview using the FileReader API.

This is the client side code

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(this.result));
$('.preview-images').append(generatePlaceholder(this.result, this.index));

switch(exif.Orientation){
    case 8:
        $('.placeholder img').css('transform','rotate(90deg)');
        break;
    case 3:
        $('.placeholder img').css('transform','rotate(180deg)');
        break;
    case 6:
        $('.placeholder img').css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');
        break;
}
startUpload(this.index);
}, false);
```

This is the PHP code, which fixes well the rotation.

```
$exif = exif_read_data($filename);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
        break;

    case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
        break;

    case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
        break;
}

imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);
}
```

My issue is that the CSS rotation does the opposite of the PHP although the degrees are the same.
When the case is 6, the PHP code rotates it from left to right 90 degrees, but the CSS rotates it right to left 90 degrees. So to get the same behavior I need to change the CSS rotation to 90 instead of -90.
How come they behave differently when they use the same degrees?

Comment: because they are 2 completely different languages

Comment: Yes, but this is math we are talking about. Degrees are degrees. A rotation direction should always be the same.Don't understand the downvote.
Is 1+1 different in JS than in PHP? This is absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP image rotation rotates anticlockwise (or counterclockwise)

> Rotation angle, in degrees. The rotation angle is interpreted as the number of degrees to rotate the image anticlockwise

In CSS it is rotated clockwise.  Hence the difference

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
Will accept your answer in a few minutes.

Comment: so yes, completely different languages.